# how to merge Hashes in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Hash like this, which should be "merged" to its uniq nested values

```json
[
  {
    "slug": "color",
    "values": [{ "slug": "amethyst" },
               { "slug": "coral" }],
  },
  {
    "slug": "color",
    "values": [{ "slug": "amethyst" }],
  },
  {
    "slug": "power-source",
    "values": [{ "slug": "110V"}],
  }
]
```

at the same time it should count the duplicate values but made uniq in an `items` array:

```json
 {  "slug": "color",
    "items": [
             {
              "slug": "amethyst",
              "count": 2
             },
             {
              "slug": "coral",
              "count": 1
             }]
 },
{
   "slug": "power-source",
   "items": [
             {
              "slug": "110V",
              "count": 1
             }]
 }
]

is there a "Rails method" to achieve this?

Thank you
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's nothing built-in in Rails that allows you to get such a custom requirement, but you can achieve it by playing around with different methods and their return values:

```
data
  .group_by { |hash| hash[:slug] }
  .transform_values do |values|
    values
      .flat_map { |vals| vals[:values] }
      .group_by { |value| value[:slug] }
      .transform_values(&:count)
  end.map do |slug, items|
    [slug, items.map { |item, count| {slug: item, count: count} }]
  end.map { |slug, items| {slug: slug, items: items} }
  # [{:slug=>"color",
  #   :items=>[{:slug=>"amethyst", :count=>2}, {:slug=>"coral", :count=>1}]},
  #  {:slug=>"power-source", :items=>[{:slug=>"110V", :count=>1}]}]
```

As you see, you can first group every hash in the array by their `slug` value, then transform the values that hash contains, mapping and flattening every array by their `values` key and then grouping to get their total.

After that you can just create the hash with its keys/values you need.

It might simplify the things a bit if you end up with a single hash, whose keys are the "slugs" and contains the items as its values.

Comment: The question has string keys so you would either need to use strings instead of symbols or use `Hash#deep_symbolize_keys` from ActiveSupport.